# PHP: converting html file to pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, yii, tcpdf

I have an html file named welcomemailtemplate.html and I need to convert that file to a PDF.

I first read this file using the following method provided by Yii framework:

```
$filename = Yii::app()->basePath.'\views\email\welcomemailtemplate.html';
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$name = $model->name;
fclose($handle);
$message = str_replace ( "[username]", $name, $contents );
```

Then, to generate the PDF file, the following parameters are set:

```
 Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
       require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
       require_once('tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php');
       $pdf = new TCPDF();
       $pdf->SetCreator("Torget");
       $pdf->SetAuthor('test name');
       $pdf->SetTitle('Savani Test');
       $pdf->SetSubject(' Torget Order Confirmation');
       $pdf->SetKeywords(' Torget, Order, Confirmation');
       //$pdf->SetHeaderData('', 0, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, '');
       $pdf->SetHeaderData('', 0, "Torget Order", '');
       $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array('helvetica', '', 8));
       $pdf->setFooterFont(Array('helvetica', '', 6));
       $pdf->SetMargins(15, 18, 15);
       $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(5);
       $pdf->SetFooterMargin(10);
       $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
       $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 7);
       $pdf->AddPage();
```

If I pass the content as follows, it creates the PDF:

```
 $pdf->writeHTML("<span>Hello World!</span>", true, false, true, false, '');
```

But if I pass the read html file content for pdf creating using following method it gives following error:

```
  $pdf->writeHTML($message, true, false, true, false, '');
       $pdf->LastPage();
```

Error message:

```
Undefined index: thead
```

Comment: Maybe the template is not valid HTML? Have you tried validating it?

Comment: html template file can be viewed on browser, so i assume it does not have any errors

Comment: @KItis — Browsers perform enormous amounts of error recovery so that is a terrible assumption.

Comment: @Vilx and Quentin yes , you are exactly right, i gave simple html file like following and it worked, Thank you Vilx, Quentin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to validate the file using the w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/.

I've worked with tcpdf before but i gave it up because it didn't seem reliable. You can also try [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) binary (only if your hosting allows you to use `proc_open`/`proc_close`). Seems a little more stable to me. It also has a [PHP class](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp) to help you use it.

Answer (score 1):

[CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net) seems to be a very good option for you. Its very easy to integrate also.